# Read file contents with unknown size

Tags: c, stdio

I want to process the contents of a config file.  The config file could be any size.  I am getting a Bus Error, after the program hangs, when I run the following code:

```
FILE *fp;
struct stat st;
char *buffer;

fp = fopen(CONFIG_FILE, "r");
if (fp == NULL) {
    // error handling and cleanup omitted for brevity
}

fstat(fileno(fp), &st);
fread(buffer, sizeof(char), st.st_size, fp);
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", *buffer);
fclose(fp);
```

I have read that a bus error can be caused by a buffer overflow.  I am pretty sure I am getting a buffer overflow with my `char *buffer`.  But then, **how can I specify the size of the buffer at runtime?**

**EDIT** - The bus error was caused by my laziness of hardcoding `1` in the fread call.  The code example has been updated to fix this, using `sizeof(char)` instead.

Comment: `sizeof(char) == 1` is guaranteed.

Comment: @Alok, that is what I thought, but it was crashing when I had 1... oh well, hardcoding is bad anyways

Comment: The C standard guarantees that `sizeof(char)` is 1.  So in this case hardcoding is okay.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`malloc(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc).  Put:

```
buffer = malloc(st.st_size);
```

Before your call to `fread()`.  Don't forget to free `buffer` when you're done with it!

You probably don't want to use `*buffer` in your `printf()` call, either.  If you're going to try to print the whole file like that, you will want to make sure to allocate an extra byte to null-terminate your string.

Comment: @Carl, when I malloc(st.st_size + 1), do I explicitly set the last element to `\0` ?

Comment: @Mad Rapper X - that should work, yes.  @muntoo, what are you asking?

Answer (score 2):

You can allocate memory with `malloc`:

```
buffer = malloc(number_of_bytes_to_allocate);
if(buffer == NULL) {
    // error allocating memory
}
```

`free` when you're done with it!

```
free(buffer);
```

Answer (score 2):

In C99, and assuming your config file should not be in the MiB or larger range, you could use a VLA:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(CONFIG_FILE, "r");
if (fp == NULL) {
    // error handling and cleanup omitted for brevity
}

struct stat st;
fstat(fileno(fp), &st);  // Error check omitted
char buffer[st.st_size+1];
fread(buffer, sizeof(char), st.st_size, fp);
buffer[st.st_size] = '\0';
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", *buffer);
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: Caution.. someone may accidentally or maliciously on purpose give you a binary file.  So what the '%s'.   Never assume the input is what you expect!