# Will assigning a large value for length of char string be an issue?

Tags: c, string

I am reading a line from a file and I do not know the length it is going to be. I know there are ways to do this with pointers but I am specifically asking for just a plan char string. For Example if I initialize the string like this:

```
char string[300]; //(or bigger)
```

Will having large string values like this be a problem?

Comment: `Will having large string values`..what do you mean? within 300 (299) or beyond?

Comment: 300 is *tiny*. Expect issues for hundreds of thousands..Unless you are allocating it on stack (local to a function), which might cause some troubles on constrained systems.

Comment: @SouravGhosh 300 itself or beyond.

Comment: 300 is a very small array.  However, I do not understand the nature of your question.

Comment: @Brandon more than 300, including null-terminator **will** be an issue, due to overrun of memory, in this case.

Comment: Assume the size if insufficient and write code that detects/copes with it.  Do not assume `300`, or any value is sufficient unless code can prove it.

Comment: Regardless of how you are reading into the array (e.g. *character-oriented* input `getchar`, `fgetc`, or *line-oriented* input `fgets`, `getline`, or *generic buffer* routines `read`, `fread` and yes even `scanf`), there are simple checks you can use to validate whether you have enough space to store what you are reading. They all start with checking the return of whatever function you are using.

Comment: C does not have a string type. You declare an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> char string[300]; //(or bigger)

I am not sure which of the two issues you are concerned with, so I will try to address both below:

- if the string in the file is larger than 300 bytes and you try to "stick" that string in that buffer, without accounting the max length of your array -you will get undefined behaviour because of overwriting the array.
- If you are just asking if 300 bytes is too much too allocate - then no, it is not a big deal unless you are on some very restricted device. e.g. In Visual Studio the default stack size (where that array would be stored) is 1 MB if I am not wrong. Benefits of doing so is understandable, e.g. you don't need to concern yourself with freeing it etc.

PS. So if you are sure the buffer size you specify is enough - this can be fine approach as you free yourself from memory management related issues - which you get from pointers and dynamic memory.

Answer (score 3):

Any hard coded number is potentially too small to read the contents of a file. It's best to compute the size at run time, allocate memory for the contents, and then read the contents.

See [Read file contents with unknown size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925545/read-file-contents-with-unknown-size).

Answer (score 0):

> Will having large string values like this be a problem?

Absolutely.

If your application must read the entire line from a file before processing it, then you have two options.

1) Allocate buffer large enough to hold the line of maximum allowed length. For example, the SMTP protocol does not allow lines longer than 998 characters. In that case you can allocate a static buffer of length 1001 (998 + `\r` + `\n` + `\0`). Once you have read a line from a file (or from a client, in the example context) which is longer than the maximum length (that is, you have read 1000 characters and the last one is not `\n`), you can treat it as a fatal (protocol) error and report it.

2) If there are no limitations on the length of the input line, the only thing you can do to ensure your program robustness is allocating buffers dynamically as the input is read. This may involve storing multiple `malloc`-ed buffers in a linked list, or calling `realloc` when buffer exhaustion detected (this is how [`getline`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html) function works, although it is not specified in the C standard, only in POSIX.1-2008).

In either case, never use `gets` to read the line. Call [`fgets`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you read the line. For example:

```
char string[300];
FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "r");
//Error checking omitted
fgets(string, 300, fp);
```

Taken from tutorialspoint.com

> The C library function char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream) reads a line from the specified stream and stores it into the string pointed to by str. It stops when either (n-1) characters are read, the newline character is read, or the end-of-file is reached, whichever comes first.

That means that this will read 299 characters from the file at most. This will cause only a logical error (because you might not get all the data you need) that won't cause any undefined behavior.

But, if you do:

```
char string[300];
int i = 0;
FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "r");
do{
    string[i] = fgetc(fp);
    i++;
while(string[i] != '\n');
```

This will cause Segmantation Fault because it will try to write on unallocated memory on lines bigger than 300 characters.